# Using Google Map

Tags: android, android-mapview

I wrote a simple code for displaying google map by getting the MD5 key. It works well when i run using eclipse but its not working properly in my android phone when i install it. It shows some error like "unknown type or package google" when using import "com.google.android.maps.MapActivity". Please help

This is my code :

public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {

    return false;
}
```

}

Comment: which android phone you are using

Comment: Does your android phone have any other google apps?.might be possible that your phone is not google supportable. Have you downloaded any app from market using your phone?

Comment: @Rekha ya i have other google apps in my phone

Comment: "unknown type or package google" is this in your logcat?

Comment: @RBS you are getting FC? or just able to see tiles?

Answer (score 0):

you need to have the api-key from google, and also should include the below line in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
```

Follow the below link and you'll achieve the loading of maps along with map tiles in android.

https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup

Comment: I did both the things.. Its running in emulator but not in my mobile phone

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/hello-mapview

read point 9 under - **Part 1: Creating a Map Activity**

also you need to include the google-maps-api to your referenced libraries to enable maps to run on devices

Answer (score 0):

The target must be Google APIs and not Android x.x 
By having it targetted to Google APIs x.x you will have the maps.jar added to your reference in the project.